# About the Stirling's approximation of the incomplete gamma function $\left|\gamma\left(a+ib,z\right)\right|$

Tags: cv.complex-variables, asymptotics, gamma-function

Let $a+ib$ be a complex number. It is well-known that $$\left|\Gamma\left(a+ib\right)\right|\sim\sqrt{2\pi}e^{-\pi\left|b\right|/2}\left|b\right|^{a-1/2}$$ for any fixed $a$ and $\left|b\right|\rightarrow\infty.$ Now let $z=c+id,\,c>0.$

> Is it possible to find a similar result for the [lower incomplete gamma function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Incomplete_gamma_function), i.e., $$\left|\gamma\left(a+ib,c+id\right)\right|\sim f\left(a,b,c,d\right)$$ for fixed $a,c,d$ and $\left|b\right|\rightarrow\infty?$

I don't know if it is a simple result, I didn't find anything in my books. I also tried to find a infinite product for the incomplete gamma but without success.

Comment: I found the following asymptotic formulas: 
http://functions.wolfram.com/GammaBetaErf/Gamma2/06/02/01/
and
http://dlmf.nist.gov/8.11.ii . 
Although the notation might be different (and it is about $\Gamma(a,z)$ not $\gamma(a,z)$) and it is not explicitly on large imaginary part but general about large absolute value of the parameter $a$, I hope it might help.

Comment: @JohannesTrost Thank you. I already knew those asymptotic formulas, but honestly I don't see how to use it in the case of a fixed real part. However thank you again for your help :)

Comment: The asymptotic expressions from my links work for (in your notation) $|a + i b| \rightarrow \infty$. So just replace the quantity in the linked formulas, whose absolute value is very large, by $ a+ i b $. Perhaps use the fact that $|b|$ is large for some further simplification.